# Integrate $\log(x+i)/(x^2+1)$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

In the first part of the question I was asked to find a branch of $log(z+i)$ which is holomorphic on the complex numbers except the imaginary axis below $-i$. I think this is $\log(z+i)=\ln(z+i)+i\text{arg}(z+i), \text{ for } -\pi/2<\text{arg}(z+i)<3\pi/2$. That said I am having trouble with the concept of branch cuts so this may be wrong.

The hint is to integrate $\log(z+i)/(z^2+1)$. I set this equal to $\log(w)/w(w-2i)$ where $w=z+i$. Then taking an integral around $[-R,-k]\cup [k,R] \cup z=k e^{2\pi i \theta} \cup z=Re^{2\pi i \theta}$ for some very small $k$. Then the only pole I need to consider is $w=2i$. Can I use Residue Theorem here and let $k\to 0$ to do this?

Is this in any way the right approach? Any help very much appreciated!

Comment: $w=z+i$?(in the substitution)

Comment: Thank you! Edited @razivo

Answer (score 1):

Think I've got it - integrate over the semicircle in the positive plane, use the estimation lemma to show the integral over the arc = 0.